# How can I check persisted data inside an integration test

Tags: testing, grails, integration-testing

In my integration test I do the following:

```
void testSave() {
    def controller = new BookController()
    controller.params.title = "Awesome Book"
    controller.params.pages = 1000
    controller.save()
    // i want to check book data here
}
```

How can I retrieve the `Book` my controller persisted and check that the `title == "Awesome Book"` and that `pages == 1000`? Can I somehow access the `bookInstance` variable in my controller from the test?

I cannot assume that `Book.get(1)` will give me the correct `Book` because there will be bootstrap data in the database. The controller redirects to a completely `Book` unrelated page so I cannot get the `id` from the URL. The only thing I can think of is to do something like this:

```
void testSave() {
    def oldIdList = Book.list()*.id
    // set up the parameters and call controller.save()
    def insertedId = Book.list()*.id - oldIdList
    // check Book.get(insertedId) properties
}
```

but I'm hoping there is a better way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using Grails 2.0.x you can look up the book by any of its properties using the findBy* methods:

```
def book = Book.findByTitle("Awesome Book")
assertNotNull book
```

Comment: Dynamic finders aren't 2.0-specific